# Coin change recursive hash (explained)?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, hash, memoization

Ruby non-greedy memoized hash, coin change solution:

```
def coin_change amt, denom_arr
  coins = Hash.new do |coin, key|
    coin[key] = if key < denom_arr.min
      []
    elsif denom_arr.include? key
      [key]
    else
      denom_arr.
      reject { |coin| coin > key }.
      reduce([]) { |memo, denom| memo.any? {|coin| coin%denom==0 } ? memo : memo+[denom] }.
      map {|denom| [denom] + coin[key-denom]}.
      min { |a, b| a.size <=> b.size } 
    end 
  end
  coins[amt]
end

p coin_change 6, [4,3,1]
#=> [3,3]
```

What exactly is being sent into this line? `.reduce([]) { |memo, denom| memo.any? {|coin| coin%denom==0 } ? memo : memo+[denom] }` (As far as I can tell it is an Array of coins < key) Can someone show me an example of how this breaksdown?

Also I get that if `{|coin| coin%denom==0 }` is true return `memo` but what is `memo+[denom]` exactly?

I understand how the `.any?` method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil.

I thought `memo` was an Array but I called class on it and it returned `Class`?

```
[4,3,8,7].inject([]) { |memo, denom| memo.class } 
#=> Class
```

In summary can someone please explain this with example output in step:

- This line: `.reduce([]) { |memo, denom| memo.any? {|coin| coin%denom==0 } ? memo : memo+[denom] }`
- Can you give an example of what the recursive code hash key/values are on each iteration? **

** ie. `denom_arr = 4,3,1`  and `amt = 6` On the first pass what is the hash look like? on Second pass what does the hash look like? on third pass and so on until finished ... what is the hash look like?

Comment: hmm.. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I think it suites SO better because codereview to me suggests that I understand the code and am looking to perhaps optimize it, whereas SO is more of a *help me understand this* kind of forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.reduce([]) { |memo, denom| memo.any? {|coin| coin%denom==0 } ? memo : memo+[denom] }
```

From `denom_arr` without elements greater than `key` this expression builds a new `Array` instance by

- `reduce` method with an empty array as the initial value of accumulator
- `memo.any? { … } ? memo : memo+[denom]` - if there is at least one element of accumulator for which the passed block is true, leave the accumulator unchanged else append value of `denom` to it.
- `{|coin| coin%denom==0 }` - block passed to `memo.any?` is true if `coin` is divisible by `denom` without reminder ie. modulo is equal to zero

EDIT:
`memo` is the accumulator which holds current result of `#reduce` and is updated for each element of Enumerable instance

Example:

```
denom_arr = [4,3,1]
coins[123]  # this invokes block passed to `Hash.new` to get default value
# denom_arr.reject { |coin| coin > key }.
# [4,3,1].reject { |coin| coin > 123 }
# => [4,3,1]
# .reduce([]) { |memo, denom| memo.any? {|coin| coin%denom==0 } ? memo : memo+[denom] }.
# initialization:  memo = [], denom = 4
# 1st pass : memo.any? evaluates to false as memo is "empty"
#   memo = memo + [4] ie. memo == [4] now
# 2nd pass : memo == [4], denom = 3
#   memo.any? evaluates to false as 4 % 3 != 0
#   memo = [4] + [3]  => [4, 3]
# 3rd pass : memo == [4,3], denom = 1
#   memo.any? evaluates to true as 4 % 1 == 0
#   memo = memo  => [4, 3]
```

Hope it's more clear now

Comment: thank you for your answer is "accumulator" a computer science term because I am not familiar with this concept, can you please explain it. Also could you be so kind as to give an example hash output? ** ie. denom_arr = 4,3,1 and amt = 6 On the first pass what is the hash look like? on Second pass what does the hash look like? on third pass and so on until finished ... what is the hash look like? Thanks

Comment: David, that is much clearer thank you!! Except `{ |coin| coin > 123 }` what is this? Also, this example is one pass through denom_arr, but how about the recursive part? Can you show how that looks too? +1 for the breakdown but I'm still iffy on this which is why I haven't accepted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @go____yourself `[4,3,1].reject { |coin| coin > 123 }` expression just throws away all elements which won't pass the test in block, ie. are greater then 123 which is none so whole `[4,3,1]` is returned. See [Array#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject) for details.

Comment: David, I know what it is but why 123? You just used that value to illustrate your example? My question is how does 123 tie into the coin_change code?

Comment: Yep, that number is just an example, required to demonstrate the code flow. I could use `6` from your question but it won't change anything.